# Training error of SVM in small n large p case

Tags: svm

There are n data points in R^p space, where p>n. We perform binary classification using linear SVM. As the VC dimension of linear SVM is p+1, it is capable to shatter n points with any label arrangement. Does that mean we should get a 0 training error? However, I rarely get such training error from my experience working with high dimensional data. Does that suggest an under-fitting?

Answer (score 1):

The VC dimension only says that there *are* points that can be shattered. This does not mean that all of them can be shattered by the classifier. For example, the VC dimension of $\mathbb R^2$ is $3$, but if you arrange the points in a line, they cannot be shattered.

In practice, I would use a proper parameter search with cross validation over to escape under-/overfitting.